# Order of execution for multiple contextmanagers in python

Tags: python, contextmanager

I couldn't find the answer for this question maybe someone could help me please?

Is the order of execution defined in case of using two contexts like that?

```py
    with open('a.txt', 'w') as f1, open('b.txt', 'w') as f2:
       <some operation>
```

Am I guaranteed that the first context (here opening 'a.txt') will be executed before second (here opening 'b.txt')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement):

> ```
> with A() as a, B() as b:
>     SUITE
> ```
>
> is semantically equivalent to:
>
> ```
> with A() as a:
>     with B() as b:
>         SUITE
> ```

So yes, since `A()` will execute before the body is executed.